# Determining dependency structure in a data set for GAMM

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model

I collected species richness data along permanent transects over the course of 3 months. So observations were made at the exact same location, where each transect was sampled once a day for 12 days over the course of 3 months.
I am trying to determine what dependency structure I need when constructing a GAMM.
My model would be:

Richness ~ Treatment + DOY + s(LiveCover)

Where treatment  is a treatment level (3 transects/treatment), doy is day of the year, and live cover is the % of live cover along the length of the transect which needs to be a smooth term as its relationship to richness is non-linear.
Obviously I need to add transect as a covariate to account for dependency, but I am not sure whether using it as a random effect will suffice, or if I need to add it as a correlation.
Thanks in advance